# Is it possible to disable the syntax check when running molecule test?

Tags: testing, ansible, molecule

I have role, role-1, that I'm testing that is dependent on another role, role-2.
I clone the second role, role-2, into `/tmp` during the prepare step, and it is imported later from `/tmp` during the converge, however during the
`INFO Running default > syntax`
I get an error, that role-2 is not found, as this role is not yet cloned and does not exist on the system.

From the debug/verbose output it look like `molecule test` result in the following command being run

`COMMAND: ansible-playbook --diff --inventory /home/vagrant/.cache/molecule/role-1/default/inventory --skip-tags molecule-notest,notest --syntax-check /opt/role-1-role/ansible/roles/role-1/molecule/default/converge.yml`

Is there a way to stop this command running the `--syntax-check`, override the default command that `molecule test` runs? Or the have the syntax-check skip certain tasks or files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that you can add `scenario` to the `molecule.yml` file and overwrite/re-order the test sequence, so that solves the issue I was having, by reordering the sequence so that the syntax check happened after the prepare step.

See [molecule.scenario](https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#molecule.scenario.Scenario)